# Google Apps Scripts (very simple) coding error

Tags: google-apps-script

Total novice here. Here's a script to clear the contents of a column, but it's not working. I've tweaked it and gotten various errors (spreadsheet Id is not defined). This is the most recent error: ReferenceError: sheet_Id is not defined

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code (sorry it's a mess; I told you I was a total novice):

```
function ClearColumn() { //This script will clear ALL the values in the status column
var sheet_id = "1RnIV4IpQSfeqVh_VDp2Qy0301zgVttSGzY9FI7T3u_w";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet();//populate with sheet name of your merge source
var columnHeader = "Template 1 Template - Send Status"  //populate with header of column you wish to clear 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_Id);
   if (ss) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
if (sheet) {
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var column = headers.indexOf(columnHeader)+1;
 if (column>0) {
    sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).clearContent();
}
}
}
}
//Set this function to run on a time trigger of your choosing
```

Comment: Do you have a column headers named `"Template 1 Template - Send Status"`?

Comment: sheet is declared twice

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you define `sheet_id`, but you try to use `sheet_Id`. The variable name is capitalized differently, and that matters for JavaScript.

Also, you try to use the variable `sheetName`, but it's not declared.

Try changing to this:

```
function ClearColumn() { //This script will clear ALL the values in the status column
  var sheet_id = "1RnIV4IpQSfeqVh_VDp2Qy0301zgVttSGzY9FI7T3u_w";
  var sheet_name = "My sheet name";
  var columnHeader = "Template 1 Template - Send Status"  //populate with header of column you wish to clear 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id);
  if (ss) {
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name); //populate with sheet name of your merge source
    if (sheet) {
      var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      var column = headers.indexOf(columnHeader) + 1;
      if (column > 0) {
        sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a column named "Template 1 Template - Send Status". That's the column that I want to be cleared.

Comment: Your code works so that I don't get an error, but it does not clear the column.

Comment: I've changed it a bit so that you can specify the name of the sheet as well. I've tested it, and it's working for me.